# Mount an FTPS server to a linux directory (but get Access denied: 530 error)

Tags: linux, mount, ftps, fuse

Im trying to Mount FTPS to a directory but it doesn't seem to work...

I can do this:

```
lftp -p 990 user:pass@10.10.10.1
```

It will connect fine.

But if I do this:

```
curlftpfs 10.10.10.1:990 /mnt/test -o user=user:pass
```

**I get this error:**

```
* Couldn't find host 10.10.10.1 in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to 10.10.10.1 port 990 (#0)
*   Trying 10.10.10.1... * connected
* Connected to 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1) port 990 (#0)
< 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.34 beta
< 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
< 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
> USER user
< 530 SSL required
* Access denied: 530
* Closing connection #0
Error connecting to ftp: Access denied: 530
```

Whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `-o ssl`

Comment: Thanks that works (with no_verify_hostname,no_verify_peer)